# Realized GARCH forecasting the realised measure of volatility (rugarch package)

Tags: r, garch

A question regarding the Realized GARCH model in the rugarch package (or perhaps quite a general question). In the original paper by Hansen, Huang and Shek (2011), they mention the model can be used to predict both the conditional return variance AND the realized measure.

I have performed a forecast using ugarchroll, and am curious as to whether this package gives me access to both, or just one of these measures? I see a RVolForecast and have been assuming this is the conditional volatility forecast (of the latent volatility). Is this not the case? If not, where is the conditional volatility forecast?

I am also curious as to how the Realized GARCH model can forecast the realized measure, given the measurement equation requires today's information for the leverage effect (in the form of zt).

The authors explicitly state it can be used to predict both the conditional variance and the realized measure, so just curious as to where they're stored!